# Positioning something from the right

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am building an App on react native in which I want to be position something from right

```
   <View style={searchDrop}> 
             <TextInput
              style={textInput}
              placeholder="Search Coin"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.onSearch(text)} />
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("CurrencySelection")}>
                      <Text style={money}> <Icons name="money" size={35} color="#fbc02d" /> </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

with following styles

```
textInput: { 
    width: "70%",
    height: 35,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 15,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }, 

searchDrop: {
    paddingTop: 32,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#3b5998",
    width: 100%
  }, 
  money: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 0
  }
```

With That I was expecting

```
<Text style={money}> <Icons name="money" size={35} color="#fbc02d" /> </Text>
```

To be on the absolute right side of the screen

Here is how it is looking now

[image]

Comment: No idea how to debug react native, but if this was regular html css, i would say that `textInput` has a non static `position`

Comment: @Jasonbamber Can share regular HTML and CSS? I will find the equivalence of react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this, it will move the icon to right.

```
  <View style={styles.searchDrop}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder="Search Coin"
      onChangeText={text => this.onSearch(text)}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.money}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CurrencySelection')}>
          <Text> <Icons name="money" size={35} color="#fbc02d"/> </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

Comment: style `searchDrop` have a `flex direction` row already. How will this make a difference?

Comment: Sorry just updated my answer, so the problem was with your position: absolute, since it was inside TouchableOpacity which didn't had any height or width. So i assigned the styling to TouchableOpacity simple.

Comment: Firstly, Thanks a lot for answering,Just tried but nope. Also, I am not sure what changes you have done?

Comment: give position: 'absolute' to your parent Component in your case its TouchableOpacity. Don't give this property to Text Component.